# Prove that the perpendiculars from $D,E,F$ to $BC,CA,AB$ are concurrent

Tags: geometry, contest-math

If two triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ are such that the perpendicular from $A,B,C$ to $EF,FD,DE$ are congruent, prove that the perpendiculars from $D,E,F$ to $BC,CA,AB$ are concurrent.

Source: Challenge and Thrills of pre-college mathematics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: the perpendicular to $AB$ through $C\not\in AB$ is the locus of points $P$ for which:
$$ PA^2-PB^2 = CA^2-CB^2.$$

Comment: D' Aurizio can you help me with a diagram and explain on the technique or idea used whence I can understand and solve similar questions.